# Is it possible to inspect a memory address of a variable in IDA Free?

Tags: c, memory, gdb, ida

Is it possible to inspect a memory address of a variable in `IDA Free`, just like it is done in `gdb`?

For example, this C code:

```
int my_number = 7;
```

Then in `gdb` we do:

```
p &my_number
```

and we get a memory address such as `0xefffde56e077` then when we do:

```
x/10x 0xefffde56e077
```

and we get to inspect that specific block and see `7` in there.

Is this possible with IDA?